# Unable to find "UpdateQueryBuilder" in springframework data 4

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am upgrading spring elasticsearch data from 3.x to 4.2.1. The support of [UpdateQueryBuilder](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/4.2.1/api/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/core/query/Query.html) is removed from the latest version which earlier I used to construct `UpdateQuery` from `UpdateRequest` object of elasticsearch. For example:

```
        return new UpdateQueryBuilder()
              .withId(documentId)
              .withClass(getDocumentClass())
              .withUpdateRequest(updateRequest)
              .build();
```

The new class [UpdateQuery](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/4.2.1/api/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/core/query/Query.html) doesn't accept `UpdateRequest` object but only accepts [Query](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/4.2.1/api/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/core/query/Query.html). I would prefer to avoid `UpdateRequest` conversion to `Query` somehow.

Does anyone have suggestions on how to make `UpdateQuery` and [UpdateRequest](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/4.2.1/api/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/core/query/Query.html) work together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the change from 3.2.x to 4.0 a year ago Spring Data Elasticsearch does not accept Elasticsearch classes as parameters to the API in order to constantly abstract away Elasticsearch implementation details from the SDE user.

From 4.0 on there is the nested `UpdateQuery.Builder` class on which you should be able to set all the parameters you did previously on the `org.elasticsearch.action.update.UpdateRequest` class.